# Appium TestNG test not working on AWS

Tags: java, testng, appium

I am new to appium.
I have created simple cases with TestNG.
It works fine with the reaol time device (Micromax with Android 4.2.2)
But when i try the same on AWS (Amazon Web Services), only the SetUp and TearDown goes through, rest of the cases fails.

Element not found is the error always.

I tried giving a

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath()));
```

of 30 secs, but still the same error surfaces.Can anyone help.

Comment: How are you approaching to run test on AWS?

Comment: I use eclipse as the IDE and maven as the build tool. I use the steps mentioned in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html. Finally I uploaded the zip-with-dependencies.zip and the apk to the AWS.